# Why is there a gap visible when I use "position: relative;"

Tags: css, css-position

I am currently working on a site, learning as I build, and I have come across a strange problem... For some reason I cannot figure out why there is a **big** gap between the top of the body and the content.

The problem can be seen at http://www.ruthpower.tk/.

Here is a [simplified example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n55J/). Why is the red background of `#wrapper` showing through above `#content`?

Comment: Anyone brave enough to follow that link? Can we get some code instead.

Comment: Something is wrong with the layout. Try disabling `width` of `#slidewhow` in devtools and it'll kinda work. It might be the contact button...

Comment: *"The problem lies somewhere in this part of my markup/css."* **+1**

Comment: I seem to have fixed it however After a few concerning comments I would be extremely grateful if someone could tell me if it looks ok (the css sheet).

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:absolute` on your `#button` and `position:relative` on your `#slideshow`, then position your `#button` with absolute values.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#relative-positioning / http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning:

> A relatively positioned box keeps its normal flow size, including line breaks and **the space originally reserved for it**.

***Update:** This [example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n55J/1/) is the [simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/6n55J/)'s solution (note the comments marking what has changed form the original).*